# C++ struct in struct in vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

My structs and vector :

```
struct course
{
    string nameOfCourse;
    string prepodName;
    group *mGroup;
    vector<lect> *para;
};

struct lect
{
    string date;
    int numberOfPresentStudents;
};

struct group
{
    string name;
    int numberOfStudents;
};

vector<course> courseList;
```

**how can I enter data in :**

```
courseList[i].mGroup[i].name
```

if I write

```
cin >> courseList[i].mGroup[i].name;
```

or

```
string tmp;
cin >> tmp;
courseList[i].mGroup[i].name =  tmp;
```

I get error :

> unhandled exception at adress 0x........ in ....exe : 0xC0000005 :
>   Access violation reading at 0xCCCCCCE0

```
void inputS()
{       
    int size = courseList.size();
    courseList.push_back(course());             
    cout << "\nCourse name : ";     
    cin >> courseList[size].nameOfCourse; //work
    cout << "\nGroup name : ";      
    cin >> courseList[size].mGroup[size].name; //doesn't work
};
```

Comment: "how can I "push_back" in..." Try calling `push_back`? Have a look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: make a temporary variable of the same type. Then push it back.

Comment: Note you cannot push_back onto `mGroup` because that is a pointer. But you can push_back onto `courseList`, is that your question? Just `courseList.push_back(...);`

Comment: Did it cross your mind that there may be a need to allocate memory to `mGroup` first?

Comment: Or maybe that `mGroup` should be a vector too? And maybe para should not be a pointer? If you think vectors are difficult I'm afraid pointers are worse.

Comment: @john @P0W I just want to enter data in `courseList[i].mGroup[i].name` but I don't khow how (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really only two ways that

```
cin >> courseList[i].mGroup[i].name;
```

can go wrong, either the vector `courseList` is not big enough for `[i]`, or the pointer `mGroup` is not pointing at sufficient memory for `[i]`.

To fix those problems you have to make sure that `courseList` is big enough (using `push_back` if you like), or you have to make sure that `mGroup` is pointing at sufficient memory (by using `new` probably).

There's not much more to say really, if you post some more code and describe what you are trying to achieve you'll get more detailed help.

Comment: `void inputS()
{  
 int size = courseList.size();
 courseList.push_back(course());    
 cout << "\nCourse name : ";  
 cin >> courseList[size].nameOfCourse; //work
 cout << "\nGroup name : ";  
 cin >> courseList[size].mGroup[size].name; //doesn't work
};`

Comment: OK well the problem there is that mGroup is not pointing at any useful memory. You need to use `new` to allocate some memory for mGroup.

Comment: Or you could change mGroup to a vector and then use push_back on that.

Comment: OK, and how I can do that? Something like `courseLections[size].mGroup = new ....;` ???

Comment: Yep something like that `courseList[size].mGroup = new group[...];`, replace `...` with how many groups you want. But like I said a vector is easier than a pointer.

Comment: OK I'll try it ) I'm first time writing here.... Why I get so much "-" ? )))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct group
{
    string name;
    int numberOfStudents;
    group(string na)
    {
        name = na;
    }
};

struct lect
{
    string date;
    int numberOfPresentStudents;
};

struct course
{
    string nameOfCourse;
    string prepodName;
    group *mGroup;
    vector<lect> *para;
    course(group* g)
    {
        mGroup = g;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<course> courseList;
    string tempname;
    cin >> tempname;
    group newG(tempname);
    course C(&newG);
    courseList.push_back(C);
}
```

Its perfectly compiling. Here's the [link](http://ideone.com/fVPpB9).